# SQL : ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I met a problem with `CREATE TABLE`:

Here is my instruction :

```
CREATE TABLE PRATICIEN (
num_pra INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
nom_pra VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY code_etage REFERENCES ETAGE(code_etage));
```

> ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis 00906. 00000 - "missing left parenthesis"

`ETAGE` exists and this table was created without error :

```
CREATE TABLE ETAGE (
code_etage SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
designation VARCHAR(30));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need parentheses around the foreign key reference.  That is how the syntax is defined.

You also need to declare the column.  The `FOREIGN KEY` is an *attribute* of a column, not a column definition:

```
CREATE TABLE PRATICIEN (
    num_pra INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    nom_pra VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    code_etage SMALLINT,
    FOREIGN KEY (code_etage) REFERENCES ETAGE(code_etage)
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9a9382c385410fd8b62634aa4c018f10) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply remove `FOREIGN KEY` keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE PRATICIEN (
    num_pra INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    nom_pra VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    code_etage REFERENCES ETAGE(code_etage)  -- please note that type is inferred
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=50457ae380173990a6ec88e416b1ca66)**

Answer (score 1):

Simplest would be

```
create table praticien
( num_pra    integer primary key
, nom_pra    varchar2(30) not null
, code_etage references etage );
```

However, specifying the referenced column might be considered best practice, in case `ETAGE` has more than one unique constraint:

```
create table praticien
( num_pra    integer primary key
, nom_pra    varchar2(30) not null
, code_etage references etage(code_etage) );
```

(By the way, note that it's `varchar2` in Oracle, not `varchar`.)